# I am a writer, and am trying to write a language for my story, how should I start as a complete beginner of language?

Tags: conlang-creation, vocabulary, geography

As a writer, I am trying to write a language so that I can name places more originally, how can I start writing a bare bones language for my story?

Comment: Have a read of the linked question, and then you could ask a follow up question in more detail.

Comment: For place name specifically, also look at this question and its answers: https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/665/designing-a-vocabulary-for-geographical-features